# source bash script in bash -c ""

Tags: bash, export

I am trying to source a bash script inside a `bash -c "..."` command but it doesn't work.

If I run the command outside of the `bash -c "..."` it works.

I need to use `bash -c "..."` because I want to ensure people are using Bash (no sh, tcsh, etc.)

**working:**

```
bash> source /neuro/arch/scripts/neuro-fs stable;echo $XAPPLRESDIR;
/neuro/arch/x86_64-Linux/packages/matlab/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/current/X11/app-default
```

**not working:**

```
bash> bash -c "source /neuro/arch/scripts/neuro-fs stable;echo $XAPPLRESDIR;"
```

In the Bash script, we define `XAPPLRESDIR` as follows:

```
export XAPPLRESDIR=/neuro/arch/x86_64-Linux/packages/matlab/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/current/X11/app-defaults
```

`#!/bin/bash` at the beginning of the script or not doesn't seem to make any difference.

Is export a "bad" practice in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable expansion in the "bash -c" is happening before "bash -c" is run; you need to do something like:

```
bash -c "source /neuro/arch/scripts/neuro-fs stable;echo \$XAPPLRESDIR;"
```